# Tensorflow : my model doesn't register after the first iteration

Tags: python, tensorflow

I took a tutorial available [here](https://github.com/Gabfranck/Movie-Reviews-Sentiment/blob/master/RNN_movie_reviews.ipynb) and I tried to run it on my dataset, it was able to compile and it begins the training but here what I got :

[image]

The model don't seem to be saved at each iteration.
And I tried with 100 epochs it didn't change anything, it gives the output of the first iteration. 
Do you have an idea what would be the problem ? (I know the code is long sorry)

```
def train(model, epochs, log_string):
    '''Train the RNN'''

    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        # Used to determine when to stop the training early
        valid_loss_summary = []

        # Keep track of which batch iteration is being trained
        iteration = 0

        print()
        print("Training Model: {}".format(log_string))

        train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./logs/3/train/{}'.format(log_string), sess.graph)
        valid_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./logs/3/valid/{}'.format(log_string))

        for e in range(epochs):
            state = sess.run(model.initial_state)

            # Record progress with each epoch
            train_loss = []
            train_acc = []
            val_acc = []
            val_loss = []

            with tqdm(total=len(x_train)) as pbar:
                for _, (x, y) in enumerate(get_batches(x_train, y_train, batch_size), 1):
                    feed = {model.inputs: x,
                            model.labels: y[:, None],
                            model.keep_prob: dropout,
                            model.initial_state: state}
                    summary, loss, acc, state, _ = sess.run([model.merged, 
                                                             model.cost, 
                                                             model.accuracy, 
                                                             model.final_state, 
                                                             model.optimizer], 
                                                            feed_dict=feed)                

                    # Record the loss and accuracy of each training batch
                    train_loss.append(loss)
                    train_acc.append(acc)

                    # Record the progress of training
                    train_writer.add_summary(summary, iteration)

                    iteration += 1
                    pbar.update(batch_size)

            avg_train_loss = np.mean(train_loss)
            avg_train_acc = np.mean(train_acc) 

            val_state = sess.run(model.initial_state)
            with tqdm(total=len(x_valid)) as pbar:
                for x, y in get_batches(x_valid, y_valid, batch_size):
                    feed = {model.inputs: x,
                            model.labels: y[:, None],
                            model.keep_prob: 1,
                            model.initial_state: val_state}
                    summary, batch_loss, batch_acc, val_state = sess.run([model.merged, 
                                                                          model.cost, 
                                                                          model.accuracy, 
                                                                          model.final_state], 
                                                                         feed_dict=feed)

                    # Record the validation loss and accuracy of each epoch
                    val_loss.append(batch_loss)
                    val_acc.append(batch_acc)
                    pbar.update(batch_size)

            # Average the validation loss and accuracy of each epoch
            avg_valid_loss = np.mean(val_loss)    
            avg_valid_acc = np.mean(val_acc)
            valid_loss_summary.append(avg_valid_loss)

            # Record the validation data's progress
            valid_writer.add_summary(summary, iteration)

            # Print the progress of each epoch

            print("Epoch: {}/{}".format(e, epochs),
                   "Train Loss: {:.3f}".format(avg_train_loss),
                   "Train Acc: {:.3f}".format(avg_train_acc),
                   "Valid Loss: {:.3f}".format(avg_valid_loss),
                   "Valid Acc: {:.3f}".format(avg_valid_acc))

             # Stop training if the validation loss does not decrease after 3 epochs
            if avg_valid_loss > min(valid_loss_summary):
                 print("No Improvement.")
                 stop_early += 1
                 if stop_early == 3:
                     break   

             # Reset stop_early if the validation loss finds a new low
             # Save a checkpoint of the model
            else:
                 print("New Record!")
                 stop_early = 0
         checkpoint = "sauvegarde/controverse_{}.ckpt".format(log_string)
         saver.save(sess,checkpoint)
```

Thank you very much for your answers :)

Comment: how do you reload the model?

Comment: With a loop outside the function , (that's why there were more iterations than 4) but I'm still wondering why it don't go above 57%

Comment: I might not have understood your question then. As I understood you train your model for 100 epochs but at the end, when you test your model you don't have the same results you got in the last epoch. Is it right?

Comment: I always get the same result actually :) , 57% but it's supposed to rise I guess , and the the valid loss and the valid acc (on the right of the screenshot) should not be "nan"

Comment: I actually say your training accuracy increasing from 0.132 to 0.276 and your loss decreasing from 3.030 to 2.600 so it looks like it is training. As regards valid loss and accuracy its hard to say without seeing how you process the the dev set